# Another way to say "would love/hate/like to have done something"

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, past-tense

I **would love to have seen** her.

How often would you use such a construction--that is, I am wondering if it is a formal structure?

In addition, could you show me some other way to express the same meaning?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This construction with the *perfect infinitive* is regular and idiomatic.

The past-form modal *would* expresses some sort of ‘unreality’, but exactly what sort and in what degree can only be inferred from the context. With an infinitive complement *would love* usually signifies a great wish or hope (greater than mere *would like*) for some future event; the particular ‘unreality’ in play might be a matter of

- improbability: *I would love to win the lottery* = *I wish I would win the lottery*
- impossibility (counterfactuality): *I would love to be six feet tall* = *I wish I were six feet tall*
- contingency: *I would love to go, if I can find the time* = *I hope I can go...*
- politeness (non-insistence): *I would love to have your help on this* = *I hope I will have your help ...*

But with a perfect infinitive like *to have seen* the sense is somewhat different. The perfect, *HAVE seen*, names an event *prior* to the time you are speaking of, not a future event. That event is the origin of some state *at* the time you are speaking of. With *like* or *love* the prior event will ordinarily be the cause of your present state of happiness:

> I love having seen her = *I am very happy because I saw her*

This, however, employs a perfect gerund (*-ing* form), not a perfect infinitive. In theory you could substitute an infinitive for the gerund (*I love having seen her* → *I love to have seen her*), but the perfect infinitive is very rare with the ‘real’ *I love*. (I find only 27 instances on Google, and none in either Google Books or COCA.) By contrast, the perfect infinitive is standard, and the perfect gerund very rare, with ‘unreal’ *I would love*. The ‘unreality’ expressed here is almost always counterfactuality:

> I would love to have seen her = *I would have been very happy if I had seen her, but alas! I did not*

Here the two senses, ‘source of happiness’ and ‘wish’ flow together:

> *I wish I had seen her: it would have caused me great happiness.*

The time reference in this construction can be a little quirky. Ordinarily the event which did not occur is one which you hoped would take place in the past:

> I would love to have seen her when she was in town last week.

But it can also refer to a *future* event which in the past appeared to be possible but is now known to be impossible:

> I would love to have seen her this evening, but alas! I have to go to dinner with a client.

Comment: Excellent answer, though I think I would have used past tense with the next to last block quote.  "I *would have loved* to have seen her when she was in town last week."  Probably with a contraction in speech, "I would've loved to have seen her..."

Comment: @JasonPatterson I would say it that way, too, but here we're into territory that the existing constructions weren't designed to handle, so there's always going to be some jury-rigging. I suspect that in another generation or two the way to do this will be with a new clitic *-də*, worn down from *would have*, yielding *Ida loveda seen her*. We're three quarters of the way there already.

Comment: Thanks. I, however, cannot find such a construction below--could you show me a site as to it? I love= I am happy

Comment: @nima "Happy" is a very loose paraphrase - but compare [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/love) s.v. **love**, *verb*: "to like or desire (something) very much : to ***take great pleasure in*** (something)" [my emphasis]